# BusyIndicator's high CPU usage in QtQuick 2

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, busyindicator

I use a [BusyIndicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-busyindicator.html) as a placeholder for an image until it has been completely downloaded.

```
BusyIndicator {
    id: bI
    running: img.status !== img.Ready
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 50
    height: 50
}
```

And here's the [Image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html) :

```
Image {
    id:  img
    visible: true
    source: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NeHi1Tg86fE/maxresdefault.jpg"

    onStateChanged: if(img.status === img.Ready){
                        bI.running = false
                    }else{
                        bI.running = true
                    }
```

But after running the above code I noticed high CPU usage (one full cpu thread) and my entire GPU was also involved before downloading the image completely.

Also another problem is that when the image finishes loading , the busyIndicator is still running.

Any solutions ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Since `Image.Loading` is an enum value differs from zero `Image.running` will be always true. You have to check the image status changing, just print the status from `onStatusChanged`, probably the image loads too fast so you see no loader.

Comment: @folibis OK.You're right . I changed the running property of busyIndicator to "running: img.status !== img.Ready" and and also used "onStateChanged" in the image item but after loading the image , the busyindicator still keeps running. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: maybe img.state never set to Ready, cause to loading problem or whatever. What does `onStateChanged` prints?

Comment: @folibis Apparently the image is loaded completely . But "onStateChanged: console.log(img.status)" just prints nothing.

Comment: Can you please update the example code with the last changes?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `onStateChanged: console.log(status)`?

Comment: @folibis It also prints nothing. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: You should be hooking `onStatusChanged` not `onStateChanged`. Also, technically it should be Image.Ready, not img.Ready.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess . Thanks a lot.That solved the problem. But why does the indicator consume so much cpu ( and of course gpu ) ?

Comment: Not sure - are you positive you are using the one in Quick Controls 2 and no the older one? This bug report says it should perform well: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50161

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I use QtQuick Controls 2.5 and Qt 5.14 in KDE Neon 5.18 linux.